# nested looping to remove items in list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two lists, both have a n of items. For example, I have list `l=[1,5,10,5,10]` and list `del1=[5,10]`.

I am trying to remove the items in `del1` once from `l`. So the desired outcome is a new list called `a = [1,5,10]`.

I tried to do nested loop but I just couldn't figure it out, see my code below:

```
l= [1,5,10,5,10]

s=l

a=[]

count=0
del1=[5,10]
for i in del1:
    for x in s:
        a.append(x)
        if a ==i:
            a.remove(i)
        else:
            pass


print (a)
```

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: `s=l` is useless - s and l both point to the same data... see [how to copy/clone a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list)

Comment: there is no use for a nested loop - simply loop over `l`and add only stuff to `a` that is not in `del1` - remove each item that you did not copy over from del1

Comment: He only wants to remove a single instance of things found in `del1`. Not every instance.

Comment: `else: pass` serves no purpose. You should delete it.

Comment: @PatrickArtner My thoughts exactly. I improved on this by using a `collections.Counter` instance for `O(1)` lookup in `del1` (just for the sake of efficiency).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic is confused, why are your iterating over the removal list, `del1`, and then within that iterating over `s` (or `l`).

This makes no sense.

Instead, just remove elements from `del1`, as you go.

```
l = [1,5,10,5,10]
del1 = [5,10]
a = []
for element in l:
   if element in del1:
       del1.remove(element)
   else:
       a.append(element)
```

giving `a` as `[1, 5, 10]`.

---

A more efficient way is to use a `collections.Counter` object.

```
import collections
l = [1,5,10,5,10]
del1 = [5,10]
a = []
dels_to_go = collections.Counter(del1)
for element in l:
    if dels_to_go[element]:
        dels_to_go[element] -= 1
    else:
        a.append(element)
```

which gives the same output as before.

---

*Note, you may be tempted to use a `set()`, but this would not work in the case of `del1` containing repeated values.*

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to loop through the del list once:

```
lst= [1,5,10,5,10]
del1=[5,10]
res = lst[:]

for elem in del1:
    try:
        res.remove(elem)
    except ValueError:
        pass
res
```

Output: `[1, 5, 10]`

Comment: i like the way you did deep copy

Comment: @prashantrana It's not a deep copy, but it is a copy. If you have objects in the list, I  think it would be a copy by reference.

Answer (score 0):

If `del1` does not contain duplicate items, you can make `del1` a set for more efficient lookups, avoid appending items in `l` to `a` if the item is in the set, and remove the item from the set once it's been encountered:

```
del1 = set(del1)
a = []
for i in l:
    if i in del1:
        del1.remove(i)
        continue
    a.append(i)
```

`a` becomes:

```
[1, 5, 10]
```

Comment: I considered this at first, but what if `del1`  contains repeats... :/

Comment: Noted then. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Well, this solution would be a lot nicer if there was a way to return a list less the first occurrence of a given element.

```
def remove1(lst, elem):
  lst.remove(elem)
  return lst

cpy = lst[:]
res = [x for x in lst if x not in del1 or x in remove1(cpy, x)]
```

But this will not work if there are duplicate entries in `del1`. This would work,

```
res = [x for x in lst if x not in dlt or x in remove1(cpy, x) and x not in remove1(dlt, x)]
```

But it is getting ridiculous.

I guess I'll leave my answer up as evidence that a one liner is a bad idea for this problem.

Comment: What, how did I instantly get two down votes the exact second I submitted my answer?

Comment: This does not produce the desired output. This would only return `[1]`.

Comment: You need to take into account repeated values.

Comment: I see. I'll give a go at coming up with a one liner for it.

Comment: @PMende Can you take another look now?

Comment: @JoePatten Can you take another look now?

Comment: @okovko I get the following error with your edit: `TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable`

Comment: @JoePatten I guess `remove` doesn't return a list. Yuck.

Comment: This is an example of trying to do a one liner getting you in trouble. :)

Comment: @PMende Well, you already got the right solution, and I wondered if I could redeem my down votes by coming up with a short solution even if it is less efficient. Didn't work out, but I learned something by doing it. Anyways, thanks guys.